# Mass Mail Merge of Custom Objects

Tags: mail-merge

With Extended Mail Merge enabled, mail merges have become a large part of my organizations workflow. Mass Mail Merge makes everything better, as its just less clicks and more happiness. Right now, out of the box Salesforce obviously supports Mass Mail merge for Contacts, Accounts, and Leads.

On the Power of Us Hub, Rochel Notik pointed out that there's a neat hack. When you click the link to mass merge accounts, it includes a parameter for `mdmw_pEntity=Account`. When you set that to "Opportunity" or to "Campaign" or other standard objects, you can mass mail merge for those other standard objects. However, you can't set this value to custom object names.

Under further examination, you CAN set it to the 15-character ID of your custom object. When you do this, you get a really confusing error situation: [image: insufficient privileges]

That error wasn't enough of a "can't work" for me, so I dig further. How can I actually mass merge a custom object?

Answer (score 0):

I've found the following very hackish solution, that definitely can't be User facing, but it might be one step on the path to solution.

Go into Chrome Dev Tools and edit HTML on the src attribute to each iframe.

They'll currently look something like: `/_ui/core/documentmerge/massdocumentmerge/MassDocumentMergePickTargetsStage$MassDocumentMergePickTargetsFrame?filterType=CustomEntityDataTemplate&amp;link_returl=%252F_ui%252Fcore%252Fdocumentmerge%252Fmassdocumentmerge%252FMassDocumentMergeWizard%253FcurrentStage%253D0%2526mdmw_pEntity%253D01IF0000002Krqu%2526visited_0%253D1`

Take everything from `CustomEntityDataTemplate` onward and replace it with the object ID. The src will now look like `/_ui/core/documentmerge/massdocumentmerge/MassDocumentMergePickTargetsStage$MassDocumentMergePickTargetsFrame?filterType=01IF0000002Krqu`. Then click outside the edit box. Once you do this for both iFrames, you can mass merge a custom object!

[image: merging works]

Is there a way to avoid having to hand edit these iFrames? Once you do it, mass merging custom objects works JUST as expected. What does `CustomEntityDataTemplate` refer to? Is there a way to shove this into a visualforce page that doesn't create invalid URLs?

We've proven that the platform can successfully mass merge custom objects, so now how do we make it easy?